# problems with reproducing the Navbar example in shiny (R)

Tags: r, navbar, shiny

I am trying to reproduce the Navbar example from the Shiny website (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/navbar-example.html) with some minor changes (see code below). However, neither plots, nor tables are displayed in the main panel. The panel is just empty and no error message is shown. When I introduce a helpText element into the code though, it is displayed. This is the same when I run RStudio on my machine or access it at spark.rstudio.com

Could you please indicate what has gone wrong? Thanks!

**ui.R:**

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("test",
               tabPanel("START",
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(
                            radioButtons("plotType", "Plot type",
                                         c("Scatter"="p", "Line"="l")
                            )
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            plotOutput("plot")
                          )
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel("Summary",
                        verbatimTextOutput("summary")
               ),
               navbarMenu("More",
                          tabPanel("Table",
                                   dataTableOutput("table")
                          ),
                          tabPanel("About",
                                   dataTableOutput("table")
                          )
               )
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars, type=input$plotType)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    cars
  }, options=list(iDisplayLength=10))
})
```

Comment: ids are unique. You cant have elements with the same ids. `dataTableOutput("table")` is called twice in your example duplicating id's.